# Creating openlayers text

Tags: openlayers, marker, point-of-interest

I'm kinda new to OpenLayers and I would like to ask whats the problem in my code. This is actually just from the examples I got from the internet but I seem can't make it work. All I want to do is to make POIs using Openlayers.layers.text.

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
var pois = new OpenLayers.Layer.Text( "My Points",
                { location:"./textfile.txt",
                  projection: map.displayProjection
                });
map.addLayer(pois);
```

and in my textfile is

```
lat lon title   description iconSize    iconOffset  icon
10  20  title   description 21,25   -10,-25 http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png
```

I've been trying to figure out whats wrong with my codes all day but i cant make it work. Can anyone help me to figure out whats wrong with my code? only the map will be shown with no popup/marker..

Comment: i really want to make something like this [link](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/dynamic-text-layer.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "can't make it work"? what is the bug/error you are facing?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, can you include them in your question via the edit button.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your `textfile.txt` file fit the following requirements:

- The first row of the data file should be a header line with the column names of the data.  Each column should be delimited by a `tab` space.
- The last row of `textfile.txt` should be an empty string.
- `textfile.txt` should be placed on the same host as original application.
- `OpenLayers.Layer.Text` doesn't work if you try to run your application from file system. Use web server.

See my [LIVE DEMO](http://gis-lab.info/share/DR/sandbox/marker.html). Example of .txt file: [image]

Comment: I made it work now. Thank. Though I have done this a while back but nothing happened.